# MYsql update new user problem

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Okay, I have searched for an error in this code for days and haven't succeeded. This is supposed to insert a new user (new row) into a table. For some reason, it does absolutely nothing to the mysql table "users." I can connect and retrieve data from the table perfectly fine. Please help!

```
        include('config.php');
        $db = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pass);

        if(!$db)
        {
            echo 'Cannot find the database';
            exit;
        }

        $dbname = $user;
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Cannot select the database');
```

(other code that I have not posted because I have tested it without this code and it produces the same result)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (
NULL, 
'$Passw' ,
'$Fname' , 
'$Lname' ,
'$Email' , 
'$Add1' ,
'$Add2' ,
'$City' ,
'$State' ,
'$Zip ,
'$Country' ,
'$Phone' ,
'$Bio')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

1 : Retrieve the possible MySQL error using:

```
if ($result === false)
  echo mysql_error();
```

2 : It's a good practice to specify the table fields when you use `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Because if you don't, and your DB structure changes, you will have to update the `VALUES(...)` part.

3 : use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inserting strings in queries for MySQL, to avoid [SQL injection problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).